# IPP QBD CustomTxnDetail not returning Inventory or COGS

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

In Quickbooks desktop version, when I run a transaction detail report for transaction type of Invoice, I have 5 accounts displayed: Accounts Receivable, Inventory Asset, Sales Tax Payable, Sales and Cost of Goods Sold.

However, when I run this via .NET IPP DevKit v2, I only see 3 of these accounts: Accounts Receivable, Sales Tax Payable and Sales. So, the Inventory and Cost of Goods Sold are missing.

Code:

```
CustomTxnDetail detail = new CustomTxnDetail();
detail.OfferingId = offeringId.ipp;
detail.OfferingIdSpecified = true;
detail.ReportBasis = ReportBasisEnum.Accrual;
detail.ReportBasisSpecified = true;

detail.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType6[] { 
    ItemsChoiceType6.StartTransactionDate, 
    ItemsChoiceType6.EndTransactionDate,
};
detail.Items = new object[] { 
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), 
    new DateTime(2013, 12, 31),
};

detail.Columns = new[] {
    DetailColumnsEnum.AccountId,
    DetailColumnsEnum.AccountName,
    DetailColumnsEnum.Amount,
    DetailColumnsEnum.DocNum,
    DetailColumnsEnum.ItemId,
    DetailColumnsEnum.ItemName,
    DetailColumnsEnum.ItemType,
    DetailColumnsEnum.TxnDate,
    DetailColumnsEnum.TxnId,
    DetailColumnsEnum.TxnLineId,
    DetailColumnsEnum.TxnType,
    DetailColumnsEnum.UnitPrice, 
};
detail.TxnType = new[] { 
    TxnTypeEnum.Invoice,
};

ReportingServices rptSvc = new ReportingServices(context);
Report rpt = rptSvc.CustomTxnDetailsReport(detail);
```

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AdvancedReportQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <CustomTxnDetail>
        <OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId>
        <StartTransactionDate>2013-01-01T00:00:00</StartTransactionDate>
        <EndTransactionDate>2013-12-31T00:00:00</EndTransactionDate>
        <TxnType>Invoice</TxnType>
        <ReportBasis>Accrual</ReportBasis>
        <Columns>AccountId</Columns>
        <Columns>AccountName</Columns>
        <Columns>Amount</Columns>
        <Columns>DocNum</Columns>
        <Columns>ItemId</Columns>
        <Columns>ItemName</Columns>
        <Columns>ItemType</Columns>
        <Columns>TxnDate</Columns>
        <Columns>TxnId</Columns>
        <Columns>TxnLineId</Columns>
        <Columns>TxnType</Columns>
        <Columns>UnitPrice</Columns>
    </CustomTxnDetail>
</AdvancedReportQuery>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--XML GENERATED by IntuitDataSyncEngine (IDS) using \\SBDomainServices\CDM\branches\3.9.0-rel-1-->
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"
xmlns:xdb          ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb"
xmlns:xsi          ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 RestDataFilter.xsd">
    <Report name="CustomerTxnDetail">
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>AccountId</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_IdType</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>AccountName</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_String</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>Amount</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_Amount</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>DocNum</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_String</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>ItemId</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_IdType</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>ItemName</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_String</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>ItemType</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_String</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>TxnDate</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_Date</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>TxnId</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_IdType</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>TxnLineId</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_IdType</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>TxnType</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_String</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <ColDesc>
            <ColTitle>UnitPriceQnty</ColTitle>
            <ColType>ids_Amount</ColType>
        </ColDesc>
        <Data>
            <DataRow>
                <ColData>6</ColData>
                <ColData>Sales</ColData>
                <ColData>-524.85</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>39</ColData>
                <ColData>201</ColData>
                <ColData>Inventory</ColData>
                <ColData>2013-09-18</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>Invoice</ColData>
                <ColData>34.99</ColData>
            </DataRow>
            <DataRow>
                <ColData>6</ColData>
                <ColData>Sales</ColData>
                <ColData>-174.95</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>40</ColData>
                <ColData>200</ColData>
                <ColData>Inventory</ColData>
                <ColData>2013-09-18</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>Invoice</ColData>
                <ColData>34.99</ColData>
            </DataRow>
            <DataRow>
                <ColData>6</ColData>
                <ColData>Sales</ColData>
                <ColData>-209.94</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>37</ColData>
                <ColData>203</ColData>
                <ColData>Inventory</ColData>
                <ColData>2013-09-18</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>Invoice</ColData>
                <ColData>34.99</ColData>
            </DataRow>
            <DataRow>
                <ColData>32</ColData>
                <ColData>Sales Tax Payable</ColData>
                <ColData>0</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>1</ColData>
                <ColData>Out of State</ColData>
                <ColData>Sales Tax Item</ColData>
                <ColData>2013-09-18</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>Invoice</ColData>
                <ColData/>
            </DataRow>
            <DataRow>
                <ColData>32</ColData>
                <ColData>Sales Tax Payable</ColData>
                <ColData>0</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>1</ColData>
                <ColData>Out of State</ColData>
                <ColData>Sales Tax Item</ColData>
                <ColData>2013-09-18</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>Invoice</ColData>
                <ColData/>
            </DataRow>
            <DataRow>
                <ColData>35</ColData>
                <ColData>Accounts Receivable</ColData>
                <ColData>734.79</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>2013-09-18</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>Invoice</ColData>
                <ColData/>
            </DataRow>
            <DataRow>
                <ColData>35</ColData>
                <ColData>Accounts Receivable</ColData>
                <ColData>174.95</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>2013-09-18</ColData>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData/>
                <ColData>Invoice</ColData>
                <ColData/>
            </DataRow>
        </Data>
    </Report>
</RestResponse>
```

Any thoughts?  I'm totally stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known bug in the Quickbooks API.  I opened a ticket with Intuit. They were extremely helpful and one of their developers was able to reproduce this problem.

However, there is no workaround for this right now.  And, I was left with the impression that it won't be fixed anytime soon.

> QBD V2: Intuit acknowledges this is a bug. (CustomTxnDetail does not return COGS transactions)
>
> QBD V3: As of this posting, there are no ReportingServices available in V3

If anyone else finds a workaround for retrieving actual cost transactions that can be tracked back to an invoice/sales receipt, I would greatly appreciate hearing about how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if those missing accounts( Inventory and Cost of Goods Sold ) are in errored state.

You can check by executing a query and setting ErroredObjectsOnly=true.

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects#Objects_in_Error_State

If the entity is in error state, you can query for the specific reason using the SyncStatus API:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

From there, you will need to delete or revert the object in error state, depending on if a sync has occurred.

ApiExplorer - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD

Thanks

Comment: No Accounts were in errored state, and results are the same.  So, that is not the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please query on DetailColumnsEnum.AccountType. It should have the COGS account. Inventory should come under Fixed Asset
Refer:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/064_reports/customtxndetail

Only the following account sub types are supported by the SDK-
Enumeration of Account sub-types used to categorize accounts in QuickBooks. Values: Bank, Accounts Receivable, Other Current Asset, Fixed Asset, Other Asset, Accounts Payable, Credit Card, Other Current Liability, Long Term Liability, Equity, Income, Cost of Goods Sold, Expense, Other Income, Other Expense, Non-Posting

For description of all account sub types refer:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/account

Comment: I included AccountType in the columns but this does not change the results.  I cannot figure out how to query by AccountType.  There are no examples or documentation.  The .ItemsElementName will not support the AccountType enum, and I cannot figure out which other property will support filtering by AccountType.  

Can you provide a code snippet for how to filter by Account or Account Type?

Comment: By querying, I meant that you need to add detail.Columns = new[] {
    DetailColumnsEnum.AccountType} too, which you did already. Can you paste the response when you add this column in your report? As I mentioned above, it will return the defined sub types. The inventory should be map to one of the above sub types(Fixed asset, I'm think).

Comment: Request:
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/ig558gtxln67n7k/Request-635151763064885068.txt

Response:
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrlptiowo8hy129/Response-635151763068831655.txt

Comment: Can you raise a support ticket here- https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Overview. Please attach the txt files you have shared above along with the report screenshot where this is happening. I will look into it.